# How can a proton contain a charm quark that has a heavier rest mass?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

Referring to this article: [Protons contain Charm Quarks.](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/a41031157/protons-contain-charm-quarks/)

What's going on here? Typical case of pop sci obfuscation of the actual physics? Are they only refering to the virtual particles that pop in and out of existence?

Comment: related discussion in comments here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/724023/proton-percentage-quark-composition

Answer (score 2):

They are confusing the content of [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04998-2). From the abstract.

> Here we provide evidence for intrinsic charm by exploiting a high-precision determination of the quark–gluon content of the nucleon3 based on machine learning and a large experimental dataset. We disentangle the intrinsic charm component from charm–anticharm pairs arising from high-energy radiation4. We establish the existence of intrinsic charm at the 3-standard-deviation level,

Any particles within a proton have to be [virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle), i.e. off mass shell, within the correct kinematics for energy momentum conservation.

It is not clear how this intrinsic makes any sense considering conservation of flavor, and 3 sigma can happen any time, so , as for any controversial announcement one has to wait for independent replication of the analysis .

Comment: If I'm understanding the paper correctly, what they're calling 'charm' is the sum of the charm quark and charm antiquark PDFs, rather than the difference (top of the second column on page 484). That would mean that their claim isn't inconsistent with conservation of flavor, right?

Comment: @JamesHanson I cannot find your page number in the link I have. The paper is looking at "valence quark distributions"  and claims evidence for charm  parton functions to have a component of valence quark behavior. I expect that the conservation of flavor is take up by the functional behavior of the  sea quark/antiquark, if their result is correct.

Comment: The page number is in the .pdf file. It's the sentence that starts 'Our starting point is the NNPDF4.0 global analysis...'

Comment: I see.  They are testing their hypothesis that some of the quarks in the distribution of quark antiquarks are really valence quarks, they do not care about flavor conservation at this point ,, just particle distributions.